# How to call jsp page as client partner link in Bpel

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, bpel, open-esb

I made a BPEL process and i successfully invoked four web services as a partners links by calling its WSDL, but now i still confuse how to link my JSP page which should be the client side to my BPEL process
i searched a lot and didn't find a clear answer
here is my jsp page code

```html
<form action="SERVLET">
  name : <input type="text" name="name"/>  <br>        
   group :<input type="text" name="group"/><br> 
  pass  : <input type="text" name="pass"/><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit">            
</form>
```

and i create a Servlet extends from HttpServlet :

```js
 @Override
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
  String name= request.getParameter("name");
  String group= request.getParameter("group");
  String pass= request.getParameter("pass");


  response.setContentType("text/plain");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  
  out.println(name+"-"+group+"-"+pass);
```

So my question is how to link the jsp pagr and the servlet, to my BPEL process in OpenESB , in other meaning how to send form data, from jsp page to BPEL process.